# How to write a text prompt in Nim that has readline-style line editing?

Tags: input, terminal, readline, nim-lang

`readLine()` doesn't support line editing and recalling previous commands, eg:

```py
while true:
  var name: string = readLine(stdin)
  echo "Hi, ", name, "!"
```

Has no editing. But if I compile that and wrap it in rlwrap:

```sh
$ rlwrap read_test
```

It works as I hope. with editable and recallable lines, provided by the readline library.

`readLineFromStdin()` almost works, but doesn't support ctrl+d, it returns an empty string on ctrl+d, which is indistinguishable from a newline.

How can I do this in pure Nim? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> is an EOF "signal", and thus you can catch the EOF in your input:

```
while not endOfFile(stdin):
  var name: string = readLine(stdin)
  echo "Hi, ", name, "!"
```

The procedure `readLineFromStdin` (https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/version-1-2/lib/impure/rdstdin.nim#L54) is not that complex, and you can re-write your own adding the above code to it.

Comment: Awesome! We ended up using `nim-noise` as a readline replacement, which comes with LOADS of bells and whistles

Answer (score 0):

While @xbello's answer is correct, if you want to use a package, we ended up using https://github.com/jangko/nim-noise, which supports C-d handling and loads of other features.